# remove() not working adding input dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to dynamically build input based on ajax returned results. However `.remove()` is not working and my solution is not pretty as I am repeating my self. Any help or direction please. Thanks in advance.

```
<input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="dataTypeInputPlaceHolder" />
```

```js
url: '/SettingTypes/GetSettingTypeDataValidation',
async: false,
data: { SettingTypeName: SettingName },
dataType: "json",
success: function (settingValueType) {
    if (settingValueType == 'Integer') {
        $("#dataTypeInputPlaceHolder").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInputBoolean").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInputStringList").remove();
        $("#dataType").append("<input asp-for='SettingValue' class='form-control' autocomplete='off' id='dataTypeInput' type='number' />")
    }

    if (settingValueType == 'Decimal') {
        $("#dataTypeInputBoolean").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInputPlaceHolder").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInputStringList").remove();
        $("#dataType").append("<input asp-for='SettingValue' class='form-control' autocomplete='off' id='dataTypeInput' type='number' />")
    }

    if (settingValueType == 'Boolean') {
        $("#dataTypeInputPlaceHolder").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInputStringList").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInput").remove();
        $("#dataType").append("<input asp-for='SettingValue' type='checkbox' autocomplete='off' id='dataTypeInputBoolean' checked />")
        $("#dataTypeInputBoolean").val(true);
        //$('#dataTypeInput').remove();
    } else {
        $("#dataTypeInputPlaceHolder").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInput").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInputPlaceHolder").remove();
        $("#dataTypeInputBoolean").remove();
        $("#dataType").append("<input asp-for='SettingValue' class='form-control' type='text' autocomplete='off' id='dataTypeInputStringList' />")
    }
```

Comment: We'd need to see a more complete example of your logic to show you exactly how to DRY this up. Also note that you really should not be using `async: false` as it's very bad practice.

Comment: You are creating controls dynamically, try using `var parent = $(this);` to find that HTML

Comment: In your success I find it hard to belive that your successData is a simple string, could you please console.log(settingValueType) and post the result

Comment: Also use `else if` in order to preserve the state you your conditional, the `else` case in your example works only if `settingValueType` is not `Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs...](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

To trigger a custom event

```
$( "#some-element").trigger( "custom");
```

Then:

```
$('#user div').on('custom', function(){
    $('#user div').remove('label');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#dataTypeInputPlaceHolder").empty();
```

Or

```
$("#dataTypeInputPlaceHolder").val('');
```

Answer (score -1):

this is not a good method to Remove textbox ,If you want to remove the textbox,can you please use Textbox inside of div element And Set Id for Div element then try it.